# Locale returns to Default

Tags: android, localization

I'm trying to change the locale of my app programmatically by user's choise using the following code:

```
public static void updateLanguage(Context ctx) {
    SharedPreferencesManager sharedPreferencesManager = new SharedPreferencesManager(ctx);
    String lang = sharedPreferencesManager.readPreference(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_LOCALE, "");
    if (StringUtils.isEmptyOrNull(lang)) {
        lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    }
    setLanguage(ctx, lang);
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config) {
    return config.locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config) {
    return config.getLocales().get(0);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
    config.locale = locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
    config.setLocale(locale);
}

public static void setLanguage(Context context, String languageCode) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        setSystemLocale(config, locale);
    } else {
        setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
    }
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Executing **updateLanguage(this)** method in my Application class.

I've several devices in which in some works perfectly but in others the Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() is set after a few executions, even though the sharedPreferences still defines another.

Someone could tell me if I do something wrong or why some devices work correctly and others do not? (It also happens that several devices of the same model react differently)

Comment: can you remove static from setLanguage(). may be this is happening due to static keyword

Comment: try to avoid use of static methods in android